# Retrive sum along with count in mongodb using mapReduce

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can i convert following SQL query to mongoDB using mapReduce

```
SELECT mobile, SUM( amount ),count(mobile) as noOfTimesRecharges
FROM recharge
WHERE recharge_date  between  '2015-02-26' AND  '2015-03-27'
GROUP BY mobile
having noOfTimesRecharges > 0 and  noOfTimesRecharges < 5
```

I have tried

```
db.users.mapReduce(
function(){
emit(this.mobile,this.amount);
},
function(k,v){
return Array.sum(v)
},
{
query:{
recharge_date:{$gte:ISODate("2014-06-17"),$lte:ISODate("2014-06-20")}
},
out:"one_month_data" 
}).find();
```

which gives me result but not the count.

Answer (score 5):

So you probably really want the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) in this case. It runs in native code operations and is much faster than what can be achieved from the JavaScript evaluation of [`mapReduce`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/).

```js
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "recharge_date": {
            "$gte": ISODate("2014-06-17"),
            "$lte": ISODate("2014-06-20")
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$mobile",
        "amount": { "$sum": "$amount" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$match": {
        "count": { "$gt": 1, "lt": 5 }
    }}
    { "$out": "newCollection" }
],
{ "allowDiskUse": true }
)
```

It's a lot more efficient and very simple to code.

Also check out the [SQL to agregation mapping chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) for common examples.

If you really do need mapReduce ( and you likely do not ) then the correct approach is:

```js
db.users.mapReduce(
    function() { 
        emit( this.mobile, { "amount": this.amount, "count": 1 } );
    },
    function(key,values) {
        var doc = { "amount": 0, "count": 0 };
        values.forEach(function(value) {
            doc.amount += value.amount;
            doc.count += value.count;
        };
        return doc;
   },
   { 
       "out": { "replace": "newCollection" },
       "query": {
           "recharge_date": {
               "$gte": ISODate("2014-06-17"),
               "$lte": ISODate("2014-06-20")
            }
       }
   }
)
```

But you don't get the same case on "limiting" results as you can with the aggregation pipeline without additional processing on the collection of results.

Comment: I have around 10million records using aggregate gives me  memory error of 16MB limit

Comment: @Vibhas Which is why you use `allowDiskUse` as a param

Comment: @Vibhas and which is always why there is a mapReduce way to do it if the other methods fail as well.

Comment: Yes you are right , but still how can I add having clause to limit results of group by

Comment: @Vibhas You're talking SQL in a NoSQL world which is not a good look. explain what you mean. Which BTW is not in your original question because I already answered that.

Comment: I wanted only those mobile number who have recharged  between 1-5 no of times , along with their total recharge amount . when I tried the sql pasted above it gave me proper results but hanged with large dataset [10m].so tried mongo but got stucked to add conditions to results obtained after group by that is , to get only those records whose count is > 1 and < 5

Comment: I wanted to say that I added  "count":{"$gte":1,"$lte":5} in match condition to your answer , but it fetched no results.If I remove this condition from your query it works perfeclty.

Comment: @Vibhas It "works perfectly" for the rest of the world. You are doing something wrong. Review the answer as it has been revised as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71943/discussion-between-vibhas-and-neil-lunn).

Comment: Maybe you need to take a rest. Your question has been clearly answered. Everyone else agrees,

Comment: Sorry you were right your query works like charm . It was my silly mistake.

Comment: @Vibhas So umm thanks for you upvote and acceptance then. Possibly missing from this protracted discussion.